# Refactoring multiple if / elif statements including inequalities

Tags: python, design-patterns, refactoring

I would like to replace the multiple if/elif statements with something more pythonic (preferably a design pattern):

```
def calculate_coords(self, num_of_chars):
    if num_of_chars <  20:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.8 )
    elif num_of_chars <  30:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.7 )
    elif num_of_chars <  40:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.25 )
    elif num_of_chars <  50:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.35 )
    elif num_of_chars <  60:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.2 )
    elif num_of_chars <  70:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.15 )
    elif num_of_chars <  80:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.2 )
    elif num_of_chars <  90:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.05 )
    elif num_of_chars <  100:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6.05 )
    elif num_of_chars <  110:
        return int(num_of_chars * 6)
    elif num_of_chars <  120:
        return int(num_of_chars * 5.9 )
    elif num_of_chars <  130:
        return int(num_of_chars * 5.85 )
    else:
        return int(num_of_chars * 5.85 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to just set a variable indicating what the number of coins should be multiplied by, then writing the multiplication *once* at the very end.

```
def calculate_coords(self, num_of_chars):
    if num_of_chars < 20:
        x = 6.8
    elif num_of_chars < 30:
        x = 6.7
    ...
    else:
        x = 5.85
    return int(num_of_chars * x)
```

Beyond that, there's not much more to refactor using vanilla Python. You might use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to look up the correct value of `x`, but it probably wouldn't be worth the effort.

Given that each threshold is just 10 higher than the previous, we could compute an index into a list:

```
def calculate_coords(self, num_of_chars):
    amounts = [6.8, 6.7, ..., 5.85]
    i = (num_of_chars - 20) // 10
    try:
        x = amounts[i]
    except IndexError:
        x = 5.85
    return int(num_of_chars * x)
```

but that's arguably less clear than an explicit enumeration of the choices.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_coords(self, num_of_chars):
    factors = [6.8, 6.7, 6.25, 6.35, 6.2, 6.15, 6.2, 6.05, 6.05, 6, 5.9, 5.85]
    comparison = 20
    for i in range(12):
        comparison += i * 10
        if num_chars < comparison:
            return int(num_chars * factors[i])
    return int(num_of_chars * 5.86)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a dict-based approach:

```
COORDINATES = {
    20: 6.8,
    30: 6.7,
    # ... etc.
}

def calculate_coords(self, num_of_chars):
    nearest_ten = round(num_of_chars / 10) * 10
    if nearest_ten in COORDINATES:
        return int(num_of_chars * COORDINATES[nearest_ten])
    return num_of_chars * 5.85
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not very intuitive, but if you figure out the math a bit, this works:

```
def calculate_coords(num_of_chars):
    l = [6.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.25, 6.35, 6.2, 6.15, 6.2, 6.05, 6.05, 6, 5.9, 5.85]
    return int(num_of_chars*l[min(num_of_chars//10, 12)])
```

The list `l` contains the multiplication factor for `num_of_chars` less than `[10, 20, 30, 40...130]`.

The `min()` function returns `l[12]` when the `num_of_chars` is above 130.

Answer (score -1):

The brand new Python 3.10 added this feature, using "match" and "case".

Docs:
[Simple pattern: match to a literal](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#simple-pattern-match-to-a-literal)

```
http_code = "418"

match http_code:
    case "200":
        print("OK")
    case "404":
        print("Not Found")
    case "418":
        print("I'm a teapot")
    case _:
        print("Code not found")
```

Comment: What are you going to match on? The conditions are inequalities, not equalities.

Comment: As @chepner mentioned my "main problem" is the inequalities!